# Inserting element to hash of hashes in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have an array. The elements in the array are containing semi colon in between them.

Array looks something like this:

```
@Array = { "AUT;E;1",
           "AUT;E;2",
           "CHE;A;1",
           "CHE;C;4"
         };
```

I want to split the array elements using ';' (semicolon) as delimiter.

By using hash of hashes I want to store 'AUT' as key and under that want to store E => 1 and E => 2.

i.e I needed the hash as

```
%HashOfElem = (
         'AUT' => {
                     'E' => 1,
                     'E' => 2
                  },

         'CHE' => {
                     'A' => 1,
                     'C' => 4
                  }
              )
```

For that purpose I wrote the following code which is not behaving as expected :(

```
foreach(@Array)
{
    my @TmpArray = split(/;/,$_);

    %HashOfElem = (
              $TmpArray[0] => {
                                  $TmpArray[1] => $TmpArray[2]
                              }
                  );
```

}

If my approach is wrong then which data structure in perl can be used to achieve above purpose?

Please help..

Comment: Keys are unique in a hash.

Comment: `E => 1 and E => 2`, both can't be in the same hash.

Comment: Okay. Then which data structure in perl can be used to achieve above purpose?

Comment: And you don't check if a key `$TmpArray[0]` exists so you'll clobber existing values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you're doing wrong assignement to @Array, it should be (parenthesis instead of braces):

**updated according to comment:**

```
my @array = (
    "AUT;E;1",
    "AUT;E;2",
    "CHE;A;1",
    "CHE;C;4"
);
```

so your script becomes:

```
my @array = (
    "AUT;E;1",
    "AUT;E;2",
    "AUT;E;2",
    "CHE;A;1",
    "CHE;C;4"
);
my %hash;
my %dups;
foreach (@array) {
    next if exists $dups{$_};  # skip this line if already stored
    $dups{$_} = 1;
    my @tmp = split/;/;
    push @{$hash{$tmp[0]}{$tmp[1]}}, $tmp[2];
}
say Dumper\%hash;
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'CHE' => {
                     'A' => [
                              '1'
                            ],
                     'C' => [
                              '4'
                            ]
                   },
          'AUT' => {
                     'E' => [
                              '1',
                              '2'
                            ]
                   }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `push` for hashes. Thanks again.

Comment: @SSHegde, note that `push` is working on an array. `@{...}` is making each element of the hash reference an array.

Comment: Sorry.. :) Forgot to accept the answer.
One more doubt, how can I add the 1s or 2s if they are not a duplicate ?

Comment: @SSHegde: I don't get your question.

Comment: Okay.. In the above hash, under AUT, under E, we have 1 & 2. Here while inserting next element - say 3 - I want to check whether its already there. If it is there then don't insert else proceed to insert.

Comment: I am really sorry to continue this again...
Other than using Dumper to print the contents, how can I print it using data structure and get it right.?

Comment: i have used the following code to print it. its printing the keys properly but not the references . 
`while(my ($k, $v) = each(%hash)) { print"$k $v"; }`
this is giving me the keys, but not the references..please help

Comment: @SSHegde: in your code `$v` is a reference to a hash. You have to do another while for it. And continue for every level when `$v` is not a scalar. Data::Dumper is really the good tool for the job. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @M42: I got the way to access those through data structures.
The exact intention was not only to print the values of the elements of the hash but in the next part of the program I want to compare the particular elements of the hash to another array. So I wanted to know where exactly which element was residing.
Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted, hash keys must be unique. One way arround this is to make each inner hash key point to an array of values for that key:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @Array = ( 
    "AUT;E;1",
    "AUT;E;2",
    "CHE;A;1",
    "CHE;C;4"
);
my %HashOfElem;

foreach(@Array)
{
    my @TmpArray = split(';',$_);
    print "@TmpArray\n";

    push @{$HashOfElem{$TmpArray[0]}{$TmpArray[1]}}, $TmpArray[2];
}

#show variable.
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper %HashOfElem;
```

Comment: I'm glad to help...even if I was a few minutes too slow in this case :)